# Amnestic Functors in Concrete Categories

Tags: category-theory

I am reading the book: Joy of Cats. I am trying to understand the notion of an amnestic functor in a concrete category. In the book it is defined in terms of fibres. What’s the basic notion of an amnestic functor? Does it have to be defined in terms of fibres?

Comment: Which part of the definition in Joy of Cats do you find unclear?

Comment: Let $C,U)$ be a concrete category over $C$
Defn1: A fibre of an object $c \in C$ is a preordered class consisting of all objects of $C$ with U(A) = C. (A,U) is said to be amnestic provided that its fibres are partially ordered classes i.e., no two different A-object are equivalent.

Comment: In Remark 5.6, the authors state that a concrete category is amnestic if and only if the underlying functor is [amnestic](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/amnestic+functor).

Comment: I understand that property. But what I was looking for was the whole idea of an amnestic functor.